# I need to make a discord bot stop its process and wait a few seconds if people spam its command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am making a discord bot that sends a message when a specific word is typed out by another user and it works fine, but I need to have a way for the bot to stop its process and ignore the commands for a short period of time if the word needed to activate it is typed out a lot in a short period of time.

I've done some work on my code to detect spamming but I still cannot figure out how to stop it.

```
import os
import discord
import datetime
import time

from keep_on import keep_on

bot_token = os.environ['TOKEN']

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('{0.user} is online'.format(client))
  print('###########################################')

enabled = True

time_storage = int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  global enabled
  global time_storage
  sentWord = message.content
  CSentWord = sentWord.upper()
  if message.content == "!start":
    enabled = True
    await message.channel.send("Having Trouble?")
    await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Having trouble.png'))
  elif message.content == "!stop":
    enabled = False
    await message.channel.send("Ok Ill Stop.")
    await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Joey will stop.png'))
  elif enabled == True:
    if message.author == client.user:
      return
    if "SORRY" in CSentWord:
      time.sleep(0.5)
      time_delay = int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
      time_difference = time_delay - time_storage
      print('time since last stored:',time_storage)
      print('time now:',time_delay)
      print('time difference:',time_difference)
      print('###########################################')
      if time_difference < 5:
        await message.channel.send("You are moving too fast")
        await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Bruh what.png'))
        time.sleep(2)
        return
      await message.channel.send("'We're Very Sorry' - Joey Tribbiani")
      await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Joey Is Sorry.png'))
      time_storage = int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
    if "S_O_R_R_Y" in CSentWord:
      time.sleep(0.5)
      time_delay = int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
      time_difference = time_delay - time_storage
      print('time since last stored:',time_storage)
      print('time now:',time_delay)
      print('time difference:',time_difference)
      print('###########################################')
      if time_difference < 5:
        await message.channel.send("You are moving too fast")
        await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Bruh what.png'))
        time.sleep(2)
        return
      await message.channel.send("'We're Very Sorry' - Joey Tribbiani")
      await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Joey Is Sorry.png'))
      time_storage = int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
    if "S.O.R.R.Y" in CSentWord:
      time.sleep(0.5)
      time_delay = int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
      time_difference = time_delay - time_storage
      print('time since last stored:',time_storage)
      print('time now:',time_delay)
      print('time difference:',time_difference)
      print('###########################################')
      if time_difference < 5:
        await message.channel.send("You are moving too fast")
        await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Bruh what.png'))
        time.sleep(2)
        return
      await message.channel.send("'We're Very Sorry' - Joey Tribbiani")
      await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Joey Is Sorry.png'))
      time_storage = int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
    if "S|O|R|R|Y" in CSentWord:
      time.sleep(0.5)
      time_delay = int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
      time_difference = time_delay - time_storage
      print('time since last stored:',time_storage)
      print('time now:',time_delay)
      print('time difference:',time_difference)
      print('###########################################')
      if time_difference < 5:
        await message.channel.send("You are moving too fast")
        await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Bruh what.png'))
        time.sleep(2)
        return
      await message.channel.send("'We're Very Sorry' - Joey Tribbiani")
      await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Joey Is Sorry.png'))
      time_storage = int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
    if "S/O/R/R/Y" in CSentWord:
      time.sleep(0.5)
      time_delay = int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
      time_difference = time_delay - time_storage
      print('time since last stored:',time_storage)
      print('time now:',time_delay)
      print('time difference:',time_difference)
      print('###########################################')
      if time_difference < 5:
        await message.channel.send("You are moving too fast")
        await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Bruh what.png'))
        time.sleep(2)
        return
      await message.channel.send("'We're Very Sorry' - Joey Tribbiani")
      await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Joey Is Sorry.png'))
      time_storage = int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
    if "S\O\R\R\Y" in CSentWord:
      time.sleep(0.5)
      time_delay = int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
      time_difference = time_delay - time_storage
      print('time since last stored:',time_storage)
      print('time now:',time_delay)
      print('time difference:',time_difference)
      print('###########################################')
      if time_difference < 5:
        await message.channel.send("You are moving too fast")
        await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Bruh what.png'))
        time.sleep(2)
        return
      await message.channel.send("'We're Very Sorry' - Joey Tribbiani")
      await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Joey Is Sorry.png'))
      time_storage = int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
    if "FEEL BAD" in CSentWord:
      time.sleep(0.5)
      time_delay = int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
      time_difference = time_delay - time_storage
      print('time since last stored:',time_storage)
      print('time now:',time_delay)
      print('time difference:',time_difference)
      print('###########################################')
      if time_difference < 5:
        await message.channel.send("You are moving too fast")
        await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Bruh what.png'))
        time.sleep(2)
        return
      await message.channel.send("'We're Very Sorry' - Joey Tribbiani")
      await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Joey Is Sorry.png'))
      time_storage = int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
    if ".F.E.E.L. .B.A.D." in CSentWord:
      time.sleep(0.5)
      time_delay = int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
      time_difference = time_delay - time_storage
      print('time since last stored:',time_storage)
      print('time now:',time_delay)
      print('time difference:',time_difference)
      print('###########################################')
      if time_difference < 5:
        await message.channel.send("You are moving too fast")
        await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Bruh what.png'))
        time.sleep(2)
        return
      await message.channel.send("'We're Very Sorry' - Joey Tribbiani")
      await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Joey Is Sorry.png'))
      time_storage = int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
    if ".F.E.E.L.B.A.D." in CSentWord:
      time.sleep(0.5)
      time_delay = int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
      time_difference = time_delay - time_storage
      print('time since last stored:',time_storage)
      print('time now:',time_delay)
      print('time difference:',time_difference)
      print('###########################################')
      if time_difference < 5:
        await message.channel.send("You are moving too fast")
        await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Bruh what.png'))
        time.sleep(2)
        return
      await message.channel.send("'We're Very Sorry' - Joey Tribbiani")
      await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Joey Is Sorry.png'))
      time_storage = int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
    if "FEELBAD" in CSentWord:
      time.sleep(0.5)
      time_delay = int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
      time_difference = time_delay - time_storage
      print('time since last stored:',time_storage)
      print('time now:',time_delay)
      print('time difference:',time_difference)
      print('###########################################')
      if time_difference < 5:
        await message.channel.send("You are moving too fast")
        await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Bruh what.png'))
        time.sleep(2)
        return
      await message.channel.send("'We're Very Sorry' - Joey Tribbiani")
      await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Joey Is Sorry.png'))  
      time_storage = int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
    if "F_E_E_L_B_A_D" in CSentWord:
      time.sleep(0.5)
      time_delay = int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
      time_difference = time_delay - time_storage
      print('time since last stored:',time_storage)
      print('time now:',time_delay)
      print('time difference:',time_difference)
      print('###########################################')
      if time_difference < 5:
        await message.channel.send("You are moving too fast")
        await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Bruh what.png'))
        time.sleep(2)
        return
      await message.channel.send("'We're Very Sorry' - Joey Tribbiani")
      await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Joey Is Sorry.png'))
      time_storage = int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
    if "F|E|E|L B|A|D" in CSentWord:
      time.sleep(0.5)
      time_delay = int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
      time_difference = time_delay - time_storage
      print('time since last stored:',time_storage)
      print('time now:',time_delay)
      print('time difference:',time_difference)
      print('###########################################')
      if time_difference < 5:
        await message.channel.send("You are moving too fast")
        await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Bruh what.png'))
        time.sleep(2)
        return
      await message.channel.send("'We're Very Sorry' - Joey Tribbiani")
      await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Joey Is Sorry.png'))
      time_storage = int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
               
keep_on()
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Comment: Maybe add an operation flag that doesn't go into your non spamming cases? Set it when you enter one and unset when you finish  the operation? Or another way would be to use your async input into a queue with max size. If FIFO should be pretty simple to handle.

Comment: could you explain this using some code?

Answer (score 1):

There is a decorator in discord.py rewrite that sets a cooldown to the command.

```py
@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
```

But for that you need to rewrite your bot to work with discord.ext.commands

```py
from discord.ext import commands # you need this
import discord

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=";", intents=intents)
```

Else you could take the current timestamp when the command was ran with datetime.datetime() and store it in a variable. Then next time its ran you can check if the current datetime is enough time ago since the before variable

Comment: hello, I spent the last while working on this and I managed to get the time stamp working and when there is spam it sends a different message, but it would still be spammy.
for example, if you sent 3 messages in a short time span it would recognize that you are spamming and send a different message but it sends that same message 3 times and I would like it to send 1 message and forget the rest. I used your recommendation for datetime.datetime but after some research I used int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp()) which worked better

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking something like this for the operation flag since you already have an enabled flag. Just add another global flag for operation.

```
enabled = True
busy = False
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global enabled, busy
    if busy:
        pass #do nothing or you can show that something is spamming
    else:
        if case1:
           busy = True
           #do stuff
           busy = False
        else: 
           busy = True
           #do another thing
           busy = False
```

I think the above will force only single actions. so not really async, but only 1 input at a time. You can allow it to not interrupt certain actions, so its a simple way to protect your code.

Another method might be to use a queue. This way would require comparisons of the incoming messages under certain rules to be spam. Once you define the rules for spam, you can then build a small checker before your runtime to determine to act on the command or not. https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html

You can use queue to queue up your commands and then pop them and check. With a max limit on the queue, you can get an error return if the queue is full. Maybe:

```
command_queue = Queue(maxsize = 5)#maximum number of items in the queue
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global command_queue
    
    if command_queue.full():
         print("We are being spammed")
         #we dont put anything more into the queue
    else:
       command_queue.put((message,datetime.datetime.now())) #you now have the message, and the time it was input. 
#You will have to determine the rules of what should be ignored or not. 
#Maybe you can even include the sender.
#example may be, any set of messages sent by the same sender within 3 seconds of the previous message should be ignored. 
        #your stuff here
       #Depending on what is available on the discord api, you can even group your commands by sender and content and insert your rules here before entering your main processing logic.
```

Comment: do I need to import anything to use Queue?

Comment: See the python page I linked. That's the library.